# Why Pods.framework has to be optional? And why does that work?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project mainly in Swift that has dependencies managed by CocoaPods. At a given point in time I decided to change `Pods.framework` link status to *required*, instead of *optional*.

Running with this configuration works fine on the simulator, but if I try to run it on the iPhone, I get the following crash at the startup:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Pods.framework/Pods
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/...
  Reason: image not found
```

Now if I just change it back to *optional*, it works fine. I have found this solution [on Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3586). But I still don't get it, even after reading [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html).

Why does it work like this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this?

Comment: @seanicus unfortunately no.

Comment: I believe this has been fixed. It currently is defaulting to required for me with no issues.